# Anchoring a layout in a view for android

Tags: android, layout, view, window, anchor

My question is straight and simple. Open the camera app on any android device. In portrait mode (default 90 degree), there's a bottom frame that consists of buttons for camera features such as Flash, Image Capture, Accessing Gallery etc. Rotate the device to landscape in any direction - (180 degree or 0 degree) and the bottom bar remains stuck to the window space right next to the device menu buttons position. How is that feature achieved? Anchoring a frame to a specific location of the window such that device orientation changes, and thereby reconfiguring the device coordinate system (X and Y values change for each frame in the entire view/window) has no effect in redrawing the frame. Can this be achieved easily by specifying attributes to a layout xml file? Or does this involve programming complex code? If programming is the only option, I'd try and prefer to keep it as simplistic as possible.

Thanks.

Comment: I googled for the official Camera.apk source code. Saw a couple of solutions from there. Seems the default official app is actually using a whole lot of Graphics package code with Open GL APIs in a pretty complicated setup. With the time-lines I have, I might as well depend on using layout_align* attributes in a RelativeLayout and handle orientation changes and pass new layout params in the onConfigurationChanged methods. Will keep posted in a couple of days if I was successful in achieving what I had desired.

Comment: Is there a way to lock/freeze/fix/anchor an entire Activity's content view to the device Window such that orientation changes do not cause the Activity to redraw the views at all? I know Traffic Jam (game-app) does that on a Motorola Xoom tablet. That would work perfectly for me.

Comment: Apparently, fixing an activity's window is easy. android:screenOrientation does exactly that. Right-under-my-nose and I never bothered to look into the Dev Guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rotate animation should be used.
1) If the display window is stuck in a particular orientation using the android:screenOrientation attribute in the Activity's declaration in the manifest file, android:layoutAnimation attribute can be used for the ViewGroup implementation in the layout file. This attribute takes a layoutAnimation file that points to any one of the Transformation Animations files that should be used. 
2) If the inflated layout is referenced programmatically, the layout animation can be performed dynamically in program code multiple times as and how required, based on the use-cases, with different transformation animation files.

Answer (score 1):

Anchoring a view to any part of a layout or anything else for that matter is done using Relative Layouts. If you're new to Relative Layouts, try out my tutorial. Hope it helps:

**A Visual Guide to Relative Layouts In Android**

http://knowledge.lapasa.net/?p=334

Comment: Your tutorial is pretty informative. However, relative layouts and child views are redrawn for orientation changes, despite locking the activity - android:configChanges="orientation". What I am looking for is anchoring views/layouts to a specific location in the window (exactly like the capture image button for a camera app, that is usually placed immediately above the device buttons) irrespective of device orientation. Sorry, I know your tutorial doesn't help much.

Comment: oh I see now, I think there is only a flag for portrait or landscape but not the other 2 possibilities. Why not try using accelerometer to determine which layout to display?

Comment: Naa!!! Accelerometer only makes it overly complicated. I'd have to keep track of a lot of layouts, coordinates for the region, keep calling ViewGroup.removeView and ViewGroup.addView(index, view) constantly. Definitely not in a mood to risk it all and go the complicated way. And OpenGL is pretty time consuming too.